# Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded in Unknown on line 0 after 1 file upload

Tags: php, linux

I know this is an issue generally concerned with batch file uploads as the default php setting should be 20 files. However, when I try and process a single file upload I get an empty $_FILES array and an error

Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded in Unknown on line 0

which appears on the log file.

The server is running php version 5.2.9 and even when I try and set max_file_uploads in the php.ini nothing happens.

Comment: What does `ini_get('max_file_uploads');` show?

Comment: Have you tried please share some code here

Comment: that is the issue, it shows nothing. the server is running php 5.2.9 which apparently doesn't even have the function max_file_uploads so don't understand how I could be getting the error

Comment: ini_get('max_file_uploads'); returns nothing, totally blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the muppet at the hosting company set up my server incorrectly. He installed it with php 5.3 but couldnt get it to work so reverted back to 5.2.9. The function max_file_uploads seems to have remained on the install and as it doesnt exist in 5.2.9 it always fail.